# Adding extra rows to a PHP index when trying to increment an element

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have an array indexed by a code, but when I try to add a value to one of the elements, it doesn't. Instead each time round my loop, it's adding on another row, like the coded index hasn't been found.

Here's the code:

```
            $aPos = array();
            while ($Pos = mysql_fetch_row($PosRes)) {
                $aPos[$Pos[2]]['t'] = $Pos[2];
                $aPos[$Pos[3]]['t'] = $Pos[3]; // I use this for sorting

                if ($Pos[0] > $Pos[1]) { 
                    $aPos[$Pos[2]]['w']++; 
                    $aPos[$Pos[3]]['l']++; 
                    $aPos[$Pos[2]]['pts'] = $aPos[$Pos[2]]['pts'] + 3;
                }
                else if ($Pos[0] < $Pos[1]) { 
                    $aPos[$Pos[3]]['w']++;
                    $aPos[$Pos[2]]['l']++;
                    $aPos[$Pos[3]]['pts'] = $aPos[$Pos[3]]['pts'] + 3;
                }
                else { 
                    $aPos[$Pos[2]]['d']++;
                    $aPos[$Pos[3]]['d']++;
                    $aPos[$Pos[2]]['pts']++;
                    $aPos[$Pos[3]]['pts']++;
                }
                $aPos[$Pos[2]]['f'] = $aPos[$Pos[2]]['f'] + $Pos[0];
                $aPos[$Pos[2]]['a'] = $aPos[$Pos[2]]['a'] + $Pos[1];
                $aPos[$Pos[2]]['gd'] = $aPos[$Pos[2]]['f'] - $aPos[$Pos[2]]['a'];
                $aPos[$Pos[3]]['f'] = $aPos[$Pos[3]]['f'] + $Pos[1];
                $aPos[$Pos[3]]['a'] = $aPos[$Pos[3]]['a'] + $Pos[0];
                $aPos[$Pos[3]]['gd'] = $aPos[$Pos[3]]['f'] - $aPos[$Pos[3]]['a'];

                var_dump($aPos[$Pos[2]]); echo "<br />";
                var_dump($aPos[$Pos[3]]); echo "<br />";
            }
            usort($aPos, 'poscomp');
            $iPos  = findpos($aPos,$PosChartTeam);
```

poscomp is my sort routine:

```
function poscomp($x, $y) {
  if (($x['pts'] == $y['pts']) && ($x['gd'] == $y['gd']) && ($x['f'] == $y['f']) && ($x['w'] == $y['w']) && ($x['t'] == $y['t'])) { return 0; }
  else if ($x['pts'] > $y['pts']) { return -1; }
  else if ($x['pts'] < $y['pts']) { return 1; }
  else if ($x['gd'] > $y['gd'])   { return -1; }
  else if ($x['gd'] < $y['gd'])   { return 1; }
  else if ($x['f'] > $y['f'])     { return -1; }
  else if ($x['f'] < $y['f'])     { return 1; }
  else if ($x['w'] > $y['w'])     { return -1; }
  else if ($x['w'] < $y['w'])     { return 1; }
  else if ($x['t'] > $y['t'])     { return -1; }
  else if ($x['t'] < $y['t'])     { return 1; }
                             else { return 1; }
}
```

And findpos locates the numeric value of the element:

```
function findpos($z, $sPos) {
  $iA = 1;
  foreach ($z as $a) {
   if ($a['t'] == $sPos) { return $iA; }
   $iA++;
  }
}
```

Instead of incrementing the values in the elements, it's adding an additional row to the aPos array and setting them to the initial value read out of the query, so I'm getting lots of duplicated coded indices.

I suspect that it's the usort. It's like after sorting, it can no longer find the correct element to increment.

The var_dump is indicating that the rows are being set correctly (initially at least):

```
 array(6) { ["t"]=> string(5) "WORCC" ["d"]=> int(1) ["pts"]=> int(1) ["f"]=> int(2) ["a"]=> int(2) ["gd"]=> int(0) }
 array(6) { ["t"]=> string(5) "SBCEL" ["d"]=> int(1) ["pts"]=> int(1) ["f"]=> int(2) ["a"]=> int(2) ["gd"]=> int(0) }
 array(5) { ["t"]=> string(5) "STOCC" ["l"]=> int(1) ["f"]=> int(0) ["a"]=> int(1) ["gd"]=> int(-1) }
 array(6) { ["t"]=> string(5) "NORTF" ["w"]=> int(1) ["pts"]=> int(3) ["f"]=> int(1) ["a"]=> int(0) ["gd"]=> int(1) }
```

I'm attempting to find how 'iPos' varies over time. I store away the 'iPos' value, and the whole of the above is inside another loop that gets the dates I'm interested in.

The reason I suspect usort is that I've done the above code, but only call usort once, and it seems to work, in that it it does increment the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was right...it was usort.

I should have been using uasort.

Sorted now.